# "Access violation writing location" Error in linked list

Tags: c, linked-list

Hello friends , whenever I write linked list code , i always get this error

*"Unhandled exception at 0x57c4e42e (msvcr100d.dll) in sample.exe: 0xC0000005:

Access violation writing location 0x00000000."*
i dont know what this error is , and this error comes when i enter value to be added in linked list.
Can anyone please tell me what I am doing wrong and what type of error it is and in which cases such error can come?

here is my code , i have just written two function just to add and create linked list.

```
     #include<stdio.h>
     #include<conio.h>
     #include<stdlib.h>
     #include<string.>

     typedef struct list
     {
        int data;
            struct list *next;
     }list;


     list* head=NULL;
     list* current=NULL;

     list* create(int data)
     {
        list* ptr=(list*)malloc(sizeof(list));
         if(ptr==NULL) exit(0);
         ptr->data=data;
         if(head==NULL)
            {  head=ptr;
               current=ptr;
             }
        else 
    {   current->next=ptr;
        current=ptr;
        ptr->next=NULL;
    }
        return ptr;
     }
     void add(int data)
     {  create(data);
     printf("%d added to the list",data);

     }

     int main()
     {
        int i=0,choice;
        list obj;
        while(1)
        {
        printf("1)create \n1)Add\n");
        scanf("%d",&choice);
    switch(choice)
        {
    case 1:printf("Enter value");scanf("%d",i);create(i);break;
    case 2:printf("Enter value");scanf("%d",i);add(i);break;
    default:exit(0);
        }
        return 1;
        }
     }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't set up your new list node correctly when `head == NULL`. Note that your `ptr->next` update is missing!

Better to structure the code like this:

```
// Create new node

list* ptr = malloc(sizeof(list));

ptr->data = data;
ptr->next = NULL;


// Link

if (head == NULL)
{
    head = ptr;
}
else
{
    current->next = ptr;
}


// Update tail

current = ptr;
```

Comment: I will try this code what is the reason behind that error? i want to know it , in which cases such error will occur?

Comment: @Priyanka: After your first call of `add()`, `head->next` is an uninitalized value in your code because you never set `ptr->next` in that code path, so attempting to read it causes your program to crash.

Answer (score -1):

Check this. I made sth similar.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct node {
    int data;

    struct node *next;
}node_list;


void add(node_list *head, int number){
    node_list *wsk, *nowy;
   wsk = head;
   while (wsk->next != NULL)
     { 
     wsk = wsk->next; /* find last element */
     }
   nowy =(node_list*) malloc (sizeof(node_list));
   nowy->data = number;

   nowy->next = NULL;
   wsk->next = nowy; /* add new element to last element of list */
} 
void write_list(node_list *lista)
 {
   node_list *wsk=lista;          
   while( wsk != NULL )          
     {
     printf ("data = %d\n", wsk->data); 
     wsk = wsk->next;            
     }                           
 }



int main()

{
    int i=0;
    node_list *first;
    first = (node_list*)malloc(sizeof(node_list));


    first -> data = NULL;
    first -> next = NULL;




     add(first, 10);
       add(first, 20);
       write_list(first);
    getchar();
return 1;
}
```

Comment: but what is the reason behind that error? i want to know it , in which cases such error will occur?

Comment: I dont know why u add me "-". You did a lot of mistakes. First dont use library conio.h and string.h. Second u forget about losing memory. Third the function create isnt void, its sth return. 4th u didnt return a int from main. 5th dont use a infinite loop. 6th list *obj not list obj. 7th What u really would like to do? Now u create a list and add to list some values, but when u choose 1 and again create a list ( u dont create another list, just the same) and add elements with errors.